# NodeJS/Waterline, Need to wait for multiple create end before response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

In my nodejs app (using sailsjs), I use a controller to receive multiple images uploaded in a .zip, then I save them in my database using waterline:

```
var images = [];
zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    zip.extractEntryTo(zipEntry.entryName, p, false, true);

    Image.create({
        filename: zipEntry.name,
    }).exec(function(err, image){
        images.push(image);
    });
});
res.json(images);
```

The problem is I need to send back all the Image Ids generated (auto incremented), but the create method is asynchronous.
Is there any way to wait for all create method end before I can send the server response ?

**EDIT: So I found a work around by checking the number of images that I get and increment an Index in the .exec method, I can check if this is the last exec and then send the response.**

```
var images = [],
    nbValidImage = 0,
    i = 0;
zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    zip.extractEntryTo(zipEntry.entryName, p, false, true);
    nbValidImage++;
    Image.create({
        filename: zipEntry.name,
    }).exec(function(err, image){
        i++;
        images.push(image);
        if(i == nbValidImage) {
            res.json(images);
        }
    });
});
```

But if someone has a better solution... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would go with [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback), since `zipEntries` is a collection (didn't test this code):

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(zipEntries, function (zipEntry, callback) {
  zip.extractEntryTo(zipEntry.entryName, p, false, true);

  Image.create({
    filename: zipEntry.name
  }).exec(function (err, image) {
    images.push(image);
    callback();
  });

}, function (err) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  res.json(images);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I was reading the Async doc and async.each seems so be the best solution for me. Thanks :)

Comment: I agree each would be better. EachLimit is also nice if you run out memory on the machine that is running this you can limit the number of files being created in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you want to checkout promises or async.

Async has a parallel function I find useful in this situation.

https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback

It allows you to run multiple async functions at once then a callback is called when all functions are done.

I think it would work perfectly for your needs.

Here is an example from their docs:

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel([
   function(callback){
       setTimeout(function(){
           callback(null, 'one');
       }, 200);
   },
   function(callback){
       setTimeout(function(){
           callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

Comment: Yeah I heard about Async, I was searching for a solution without using a new library but I think I will need this soon or later :)